# Return JSON object from SQLAlchemy, Flask for 3 related tables

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I got this model model.py. It has 3 tables , Test,Area,Issue
 A test has multiples areas and each area many issues:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

Base = declarative_base()


class Test(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    number = Column(String(30))
    status = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    start_date = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    closed_date = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    description = Column(String(500))
    contact = Column(String(200))

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        # Returns object data in easily serializable format
        return{
            'id': self.id,
            'type': self.type,
            'number': self.number,
            'status': self.status,
            'start_date': self.start_date,
            'closed_date': self.closed_date,
            'description': self.description,
            'contact': self.contact
        }


class Area(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'area'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    test_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('test.id'))
    test = relationship(Test, backref='areas')

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        # Returns object data in easily serializable format
        return{
            'name': self.name,
            'id': self.id
        }


class Issue(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'issue'
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    reference_number = Column(String(20), nullable=True)
    status = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    area_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('area.id'))
    area = relationship(Area, backref='issues')

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        # Returns object data in easily serializable format
        return{
            'name': self.name,
            'id': self.id,
            'reference_number': self.price,
            'status': self.status
        }


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///appsecurity.db?check_same_thread=False')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I want to return a JSON for the result of a query that will bring back , a test with all its areas and all the issues inside each area:

This is the SQLAlchemy query:

```
def getTestWithAreasAndIssues(id):
    test = (session.query(Test, Area, Issue)
            .join(Area)
            .join(Issue)
            .options(
                joinedload(Test.areas).
                joinedload(Area.issues)
            )
            .filter(Test.id == id)
            .filter(Test.id == Area.test_id)
            .filter(Area.id == Issue.area_id)
            ).all()
    return test
```

That is in my opinion correct and equivalent to this sqlite3 query:

```
sqlite> select * from test, area, issue where area.test_id=test.id and issue.area_id=area.id and test.id=4;

4|Web|Test 11111|Open|2018-07-23 01:59:11.932234|2018-07-23 01:59:11|Second Test With Issues Third Attemp|david@no.us|12|Encryption|4|Weak Encryption|1|701|12|N
4|Web|Test 11111|Open|2018-07-23 01:59:11.932234|2018-07-23 01:59:11|Second Test With Issues Third Attemp|david@no.us|12|Encryption|4|ATS not in used|2|702|12|N
4|Web|Test 11111|Open|2018-07-23 01:59:11.932234|2018-07-23 01:59:11|Second Test With Issues Third Attemp|david@no.us|13|Authentication|4|Basic Authentication|3|701|13|N
4|Web|Test 11111|Open|2018-07-23 01:59:11.932234|2018-07-23 01:59:11|Second Test With Issues Third Attemp|david@no.us|20|Information|4|Sensitive Information on disk|4|103|20|N
4|Web|Test 11111|Open|2018-07-23 01:59:11.932234|2018-07-23 01:59:11|Second Test With Issues Third Attemp|david@no.us|20|Information|4|Password stored in cookies |5|104|20|N
4|Web|Test 11111|Open|2018-07-23 01:59:11.932234|2018-07-23 01:59:11|Second Test With Issues Third Attemp|david@no.us|20|Information|4|Not rate limited in API resources|6|701|20|N
sqlite>
```

And for clarify more here is the result of the sqlalchemy:

This is the response from SQLALchemy

```
[(<model.Test object at 0x7f15322e8190>, <model.Area object at 0x7f15322e8210>, <model.Issue object at 0x7f15322e8450>), 
(<model.Test object at 0x7f15322e8190>, <model.Area object at 0x7f15322e8210>, <model.Issue object at 0x7f15322e8710>), 
(<model.Test object at 0x7f15322e8190>, <model.Area object at 0x7f15322e82d0>, <model.Issue object at 0x7f15322e83d0>), 
(<model.Test object at 0x7f15322e8190>, <model.Area object at 0x7f15322e8650>, <model.Issue object at 0x7f15322e8950>), 
(<model.Test object at 0x7f15322e8190>, <model.Area object at 0x7f15322e8650>, <model.Issue object at 0x7f15322e88d0>), 
(<model.Test object at 0x7f15322e8190>, <model.Area object at 0x7f15322e8650>, <model.Issue object at 0x7f15322e8850>)]
```

Could someone help me in finding some way of return a JSON object out of this ?

Comment: Keeping on this and looking around for severals hours last  night  , I see three possible solutions : I-Create myself a method that do this so I will create a method that will take the result tables coming from SQLalchemy and split it in Array and later put those array into a dictionary . II-Use a library that does this ( I do not know of any, but Im certain it should exist) III-Maybe improve my model so I can do it somehow better from Python without need to do I or II . I will keep working and post my results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this file
I had an issue and was calling the wrong function , but the file itself is ok and I could correctly call json.dumps(result) and return the correct JSON to the user as under from flask

response = make_response(json.dumps(result,cls=MyEncoder1), 200)
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
return response

I used the cls parameter to fix an issue with Encoding datetime, as json.dumps failed while decoding datetime parameters

See the code for the Encoder here

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
import json

class MyEncoder1(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        """
        default method is used if there is an unexpected object type.
        datetime will be converted to string
        """
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            obj = str(obj)
        else:
            obj = super(MyEncoder1, self).default(obj)
        print obj
        return obj
```

Thanks and I hope this post helps anyone struggling with JSON operation with Flask and SQLAlchemy.

I WOULD LIKE TO SEE IMPROVEMENTS TO THIS CODE
WHAT COULD BE DONE DIFFERENTLY , WHAT CAN BE DONE BETTER